# Can I use meteor + react.js for mobile apps?

Tags: javascript, mobile, meteor, reactjs

I have a question. Can I use meteor and react.js to create a mobile app for both Android and IOS? Does anyone have such an app in production? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can wrap it in Cordova (PhoneGap), if that is what you mean. Check out this [Devshop Tech Talk on YouTube] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeY1mZhvDy4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor 1.2 is totally compatible with React.

Just use `meteor add react` to integrate React with your Meteor App.

Then develop your app normally.

Finally for see your app running on an iOS simulator use:

`meteor install-sdk ios`
`meteor add-platform ios`
`meteor run ios`

For android simulator use:

`meteor install-sdk android`
`meteor add-platform android`
`meteor run android`

After that you should see a simulator with your app.

For more references check this link (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Comment: Thanks you! was my first time!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this package: https://github.com/reactjs/react-meteor

It should allow to integrate reactjs in meteor. And meteor [allows you to create mobile apps](https://www.meteor.com/try/7)